# Python 2.7: dictionary (switch statement) values

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, hex

Python 2.7: dictionary (switch statement) values

I'm decoding (a string array of) hex values to a floats and I'd like to use a dictionary to store the resultant float values though I can't see how to.
For a quick fix I've used a if-elif statement to do this - is it possible to use a dictionary to accomplish this? This is my code so far:

[image]

```
# assume data is in IEEE 754 format
import struct
from binascii import unhexlify

inputData  = ['41', 'b8', '00', '00', '40', '5d', '70', 'a4', '40', '07', 'ae', '14']
outputData = {'first': 0.0, 'second': 0.0, 'third': 0.0}
for offset in [0, 4, 8]:
    valueBytes = inputData[offset:offset+4]
    value      = struct.unpack('>f',unhexlify(''.join(valueBytes)))[0]
    print valueBytes, '=>', value
    if offset == 0:
        outputData['first']  = value
    elif offset == 4:
        outputData['second'] = value
    elif offset == 8:
        outputData['third'] = value
    # could use if-else here but I'd like a dictionary
    #options = {
    #    0 : outputData['first']  = value,
    #    4 : outputData['second'] = value,        
    #    8 : outputData['third']  = value
    #    }[offset]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyhton does not hava a switch statement. In most cases where you would use a switch in another language, you'd use a dict lookup in python instead:

```
inputData  = ['41', 'b8', '00', '00', '40', '5d', '70', 'a4', '40', '07', 'ae', '14']
outputData = {'first': 0.0, 'second': 0.0, 'third': 0.0}
offset_to_key = {0: 'first', 4: 'second', 8: 'third'}
for offset in [0, 4, 8]:
    valueBytes = inputData[offset:offset+4]
    value      = struct.unpack('>f',unhexlify(''.join(valueBytes)))[0]
    print valueBytes, '=>', value
    outputData[offset_to_key[offset]] = value
```

Another possibility would be to specify the key as loop variable:

```
inputData  = ['41', 'b8', '00', '00', '40', '5d', '70', 'a4', '40', '07', 'ae', '14']
outputData = {'first': 0.0, 'second': 0.0, 'third': 0.0}
for offset, dictkey in zip([0, 4, 8], ['first', 'second', 'third']):
    valueBytes = inputData[offset:offset+4]
    value      = struct.unpack('>f',unhexlify(''.join(valueBytes)))[0]
    print valueBytes, '=>', value
    outputData[dictkey] = value
```